# Convertir byte en UTF-8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csv, utf-8

Tengo un programa que llama a un servicio web y el resultado en bytes es exportado el en un archivo .csv.

Este servicio web en el codigo es 'client'

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es convertir el resultado en UTF-8 pero no logro hacerlo.

He intendado de varias formas pero no logro cambiar en formato.

Como podria hacer esto?

Este es mi codigo:

```
System.IO.Stream bytesRead = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

string csvReportOutputFile = String.Format(@"C:/ExportReport/report.csv"); 

var export = client.GetCsvReportData(out bytesRead);

using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(csvReportOutputFile))
{
    byte[] bytesInStream = StreamReadToEnd(bytesRead);    
    fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
}
```

Tengo esta funcion que lee el stream del resultado.

```
public static byte[] StreamReadToEnd(System.IO.Stream stream)
{
    long originalPosition = 0;

    if (stream.CanSeek)
    {
        originalPosition = stream.Position;
        stream.Position = 0;
    }

    try
    {
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];

        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(readBuffer, totalBytesRead, readBuffer.Length - totalBytesRead)) > 0)
        {
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

            if (totalBytesRead == readBuffer.Length)
            {
                int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();
                if (nextByte != -1)
                {
                    byte[] temp = new byte[readBuffer.Length * 2];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, temp, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                    Buffer.SetByte(temp, totalBytesRead, (byte)nextByte);
                    readBuffer = temp;
                    totalBytesRead++;
                }
            }
        }

        byte[] buffer = readBuffer;
        if (readBuffer.Length != totalBytesRead)
        {
            buffer = new byte[totalBytesRead];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, totalBytesRead);
        }
        return buffer;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream.CanSeek)
        {
            stream.Position = originalPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola! para pasar en limpio, vos necesitas pasar un `byte[]` a un string en `UTF8`?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal, hola si exactamente

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo, podes usar el método [`GetString(byte[])`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Text.Encoding.GetString);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) que se encuentra dentro de la propiedad [`UTF8`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Text.Encoding.GetString);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) en la clase [`Encoding`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf8?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8)

```
string utf8result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tubytearray);
```

*Referencia a respuesta en SOEn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3406197/5213794*